# How can we change spider chart background color?

Tags: javascript, charts, background-color, lightningchart, spider-chart

Refer this image to see what i am looking at:

[image: [1]]

With this code :

```js
const colors = [ColorRGBA(0, 255, 125, 0), ColorRGBA(255, 125, 0, 0)]
const fillStyles = colors.map((color) => new SolidFill({ color: color.setA(150) }))

const chart = db.createSpiderChart({
  columnIndex: 1,
  rowIndex: 0,
  columnSpan: 1,
  rowSpan: 2
})
  .setTitle('Spider chart')
  .setBackgroundFillStyle(fillStyles[0])
```

I am getting this result :

[image: [2]]

Comment: For anyone interested you can edit the chart here: [LightningChart JS Interactive Examples - Dashboard with LegendBox](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0500-dashboardWithLegendBox.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the background color of the chart by using the method  [setChartBackgroundFillStyle](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.0/classes/spiderchart.html#setchartbackgroundfillstyle) with the wanted `FillStyle`

For example:

```
const colors = [ColorRGBA(0, 255, 125, 0), ColorRGBA(255, 125, 0, 0)]
const fillStyles = colors.map((color) => new SolidFill({ color: color.setA(150) }))

const chart = db.createSpiderChart({
  columnIndex: 1,
  rowIndex: 0,
  columnSpan: 1,
  rowSpan: 2
})
  .setTitle('Spider chart')
  .setBackgroundFillStyle(fillStyles[0])
  .setChartBackgroundFillStyle(fillStyles[1])
```